# Eclipse command not found in linux while in the eclipse folder

Tags: linux, eclipse, installation

I downloaded the correct version of eclipse that will work on my linux machine from the website. The structure looks like this: eclipse/eclipse. I was in the eclipse folder, and I typed in eclipse in linux to start the IDE. It showed the error: eclipse command not found.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal. For safety, the current directory is not part of the path used to find executables. Use `./eclipse` to refer to the binary explicitly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a follow up on that. what command should I use if I want to run the eclipse in another folder, like in my git repository folder. Not very familiar with ./ thing in linux.

Comment: Just specify the necessary path to the binary, whether that's with the current directory, '.', or something else.

Comment: you mentioned that the eclipse in the eclipse folder is not the executable. But how is ./eclipse in the eclipse folder different from getting the eclipse in the eclipse folder since ./ means the current directory. So I guess my question is that how do I find the path to get the executables? Thanks!

Comment: That *was* the executable, you just ran it without relying on the current directory being part of the searchable $PATH (https://superuser.com/questions/156582/why-is-not-in-the-path-by-default). Just refer to the location correctly and you'll be fine.